# How to serialize enums to different property name using json.net

Tags: c#, serialization, enums, json.net

I have the following enum

```
public enum PermissionType
{
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "can_fly")]
  PermissionToFly,
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "can_swim")]
  PermissionToSwim
};
```

and a class with this property

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "permissions", ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public IList<PermissionType> PermissionKeynames { get; set; }`
```

I want to serialize the list of enumerations to a list of strings, and that serialize list use the string specified in `PropertyName` (such as "can_swim") instead of the property's actual name "PermissionToSwim".  However, whenever I call JsonConvert.SerializeObject, I end up with

```
"permission_keynames":["PermissionToFly","PermissionToSwim"]
```

instead of my desired

```
"permission_keynames":["can_fly","can_swim"]
```

I want to keep the phrase "PermissionToSwim" for use in my code, serialize to another word.  Any idea how I can achieve this?  My gut says that the annotation is the culprit, but I haven't been able to find the correct one.

Comment: In case anyone in the future is having the opposite issue (deserializing to an enum with differently-named values), check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799769/parsing-an-enumeration-in-json-net).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

[Looks like](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/StringEnumConverter.cs#L221) you can make this work using the [`EnumMember` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) (found in System.Runtime.Serialization).

```
public enum PermissionType
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "can_fly")]
    PermissionToFly,

    [EnumMember(Value = "can_swim")]
    PermissionToSwim
}
```

If you use those attributes you should also not need to set the `ItemConverterType` in the `JsonProperty` attribute on the list.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  I actually saw this earlier but thought it wouldn't work with json.net because it was a System.Runtime.Serialization annotation.  Little did I know...

Comment: This worked for me, except, regarding your last comment, I still needed to use the StringEnumConverter -- otherwise, it went back to deserializing to integers.

Comment: I agree with @Gyromite. 
That's what I had to do it to make it work:

1) to serialize:
`var js = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(PermissionType.PermissionToFly, new StringEnumConverter());`

2) to deserialize:
`var permissionType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PermissionType>(js, new StringEnumConverter());`

Comment: Note that this is not Json.NET-specific and may also affect other methods of serializing the enum such as XML serialization.

Answer (score 1):

You can define custom converter for serializing enums by JsonProperty attribute with System.Reflection.

```
public class EnumByAttributesConverter<TEnum> : JsonConverter<TEnum>
    where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, TEnum value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var valueName = value.ToString();
        var membersAttributes = GetMemberAttributePairs(value.GetType());
        var propertyName = membersAttributes.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == valueName)
            .Attribute?.PropertyName;
        writer.WriteValue(propertyName ?? valueName);
    }

    public override TEnum ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, TEnum existingValue, 
        bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var name = reader.Value as string;
        var membersAttributes = GetMemberAttributePairs(objectType);
        var memberName = membersAttributes
            .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Attribute.PropertyName == name).Name;
        return Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(memberName ?? name, out var parsedResult)
            ? parsedResult
            : default;
    }

    private IReadOnlyCollection<(string Name, JsonPropertyAttribute Attribute)> GetMemberAttributePairs(Type type) =>
        type.GetMembers()
            .Select(member => (member.Name,
                Attribute: member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute), false)
                        .FirstOrDefault() as JsonPropertyAttribute))
            .Where(p => p.Attribute != null).ToArray();
}
```

You still have to define JsonConverter attribute, but that way avoid to mix System.Runtime.Serialization and Newtonsoft.Json in project.