# Serialize enum to JSON using attribute value, not enum value

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have an enum which contains attributes on each value, for example:

```
public enum MyEnum 
{
    [MyEnumAttribute("val01")]
    Value01,
    
    [MyEnumAttribute("val02")]
    Value02
}
```

This enum is used as a property in a class, for example:

```
public class MyDataObject 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyEnum EnumOption { get; set; }
}
```

How can I serialize this object to JSON (preferably using Newtonsoft.Json), using the value from `MyEnumAttribute` instead of the enum value?

#### Edit:

Ideally, I'd also like to be able to deserialise the JSON into an instance of `MyDataObject`, mapping the values `val01` to `MyEnum.Value01`, `val02` to `MyEnum.Value02` etc

Comment: or if you don't want custom converter - then easy & dirty way - add ignore to enum property + provide additional string property with get / set logic for (de)serialization based on custom attributes

Comment: Does it have to be a *custom* attribute?  Json.NET's `StringEnumConverter` does support `EnumMemberAttribute` as shown in [How to serialize enums to different property name using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26391632) and [parsing an enumeration in JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7799769).

Comment: @dbc You're absolutely right, and that's all I need in the short term, thanks. At some point I'll need to include more properties in the attribute, in which case it sounds like I'll need a custom enum converter, which doesnt seem too bad.